# Scraping for id="author" using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am learning how to use Python for web scraping and was given the following html file:

```
<html><head><title>The Website Title</title></head>
<body>
<p>Download my <strong>Python</strong> book from <a href="http://inventwithpython.com">my website</a>.</p>
<p class="slogan">Learn Python the easy way!</p>
<p>By <span id="author">Al Sweigart</span></p>
</body></html>
```

I opened the file and read it to the variable exampleSoup. I then wanted to scrape it for the author and was told to use

```
elems = exampleSoup.select('#author')
```

This, however, returned an empty list.
I then tried

```
elems = exampleSoup.select('span#author')
```

and got my desired output.

My question is, why didn't the first method work in this instance?

Comment: Try using `.select("[id='author']")` and let me know what it produces.

Comment: Yes, that worked as desired. So did .select('#"author"'). I guess the quotes around "author" make a difference to either the current build of Beautiful Soup or Python.

Comment: @ToddBurus No sir, quotes around author don't matter.

Comment: This can't be reproduced with current versions of BeautifulSoup and the various parser backends. We'd need to see more details, such as how you created `exampleSoup` and what `import bs4; print(bs4.__version__)` outputs, as well as the same `__version__` attribute for `html5lib` or `lxml.etree` if you use either parser instead of the one bundled with Python. It is more likely to be a BeautifulSoup version problem however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the version of python is causing this issue

> I'm usimg : Python 3.6.2 and bs 4.6.0

and here is my approach

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

content = '<html><head><title>The Website Title</title></head><body><p>Download my <strong>Python</strong> book from <a href="http://inventwithpython.com">my website</a>.</p><p class="slogan">Learn Python the easy way!</p><p>By <span id="author">Al Sweigart</span></p></body></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

result1 = soup.select("[id='author']")
print (result1) # output [<span id="author">Al Sweigart</span>]

result2 = soup.select('#author')
print (result2) # output [<span id="author">Al Sweigart</span>]

result3 = soup.select('span#author')
print (result3) # output [<span id="author">Al Sweigart</span>]

result4 = soup.span # this how the decumentation did it 
print (result4) # output <span id="author">Al Sweigart</span>
```

Comment: That's possible. I'm using Python 3.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    htmlFile = """<html>
    <head>
    <title>The Website Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<p>Download my <strong>Python</strong> book from <a href="http://inventwithpython.com">my website</a>.</p>
<p class="slogan">Learn Python the easy way!</p>
<p>By <span id="author">Al Sweigart</span></p>
</body>
</html>"""

    soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlFile, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.select("#author"))
```

I received the output as it was desired:
`[<span id="author">Al Sweigart</span>]`
maybe you are using older version of the module.

Comment: I had just installed BeautifulSoup 4.6.0. Oddly enough, I ran this program as you described and got the desired output. But then I ran elems = soup.select("#author") and the print command, and it once again gave me an empty list!